# Java using the Vector class - Matrix

Tags: java, vector, matrix

So I have the following problem. I parsed out the text from a .txt file, and the text contained two sets of data that I needed to collect - certain ID and a set of double numbers linked to each ID. For example:

```
ID1:
[3.21
23.3
15
.
.]
ID2:
[.
.
.].
```

The way I imagined collecting the data was through Vector - matrix, or 
`Vector<Vector<String>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<String>>();`. So basically I would read each ID as a first element (position 0) of each row in the matrix, and then I would read double numbers as Strings in the following rows respectively. I will do the conversion later. Now check my code:

```
Vector<Vector<String>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
Vector<String> array = new Vector<>();

while(s.hasNext())
{
    String data = s.next();

    Matcher matcherDouble = patternDouble.matcher(data);
    Matcher matcherID = patternID.matcher(data);

    if(matcherID.find())
    {
        System.out.println("found: " + matcherID.group(1));

        /*********************************/
        if(!(array.isEmpty()))
        {
            matrix.add(array);
        }
        /**********************************/
        array.clear();
        array.add(matcherID.group(1));
    }

    if(matcherDouble.find())
    {
        System.out.println("found: " + matcherDouble.group(3));
        array.add(matcherDouble.group(3));
    }
}
```

I parsed out everything correctly so this part of code is enough to explain my problem. So because I need a matrix, I decided to collect arrays individually and at the same tame to add them to the matrix. Depending on the number of different ID-s I'll have as many arrays to add.

In the first cycle through `if( matcherID.find())`, I wont add an array to matrix because that is when I am getting my first ID and I still need the other elements before i add an array to matrix. Every time after this one, my condition `if(!( array.isEmpty()))` will be met and i will add another array to matrix.

My problem is that once I have added the first array to the matrix -  matrix starts to change dynamically as I change the array. For example after I have added new array when I execute the following line  `array.clear()` in the next step it deletes the array from my matrix? How can I prevent that? I thought it will be stored in matrix, but matrix and array keep the connection.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please provide a small sample of input, your actual output and your expected output.

Comment: my input from .txt file is something like this
statistics
a1
population1:
[4.23
+9.98
15
+3.23
+9.98
29]
population2:
[20
+6.5
13
+1.23
+2.98]
.

Comment: my matrix should like something like
[[population1, 4.23, 9.98, 15, 3.23, 9.98, 29], [population2, 20, 6.5, 13, 1.23, 2.98]]

but what i get in this case is 
[[population2, 20, 6.5, 13, 1.23, 2.98], [population2, 20, 6.5, 13, 1.23, 2.98]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're repeatedly adding the same `Vector<String>` and clearing it.  You need to create a new `Vector<String>` for each row.

I'm not entirely clear on the logic of what you're doing, but correcting this issue might be as simple as changing the line

```
array.clear();
```

to

```
array = new Vector<>();
```

This is because all these objects are really held as references, and the entries (rows) you're adding to your matrix really are just references to the same object that the `array` variable references.  If you want them to be different, you have to create new objects.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! I basically had the problem that my matrix stays dynamically connected with array, and i thought that once i add an array to matrix their link is broken, so once i clear the array i could add another one to the matrix but that was not the case. Now it works!

Comment: Great!  If you clean up your code a little more, it may look pretty much like what Elliott Frisch posted.  Please accept one of the answers, now that the problem's solved.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you really need to make four changes as follows

```
Vector<Vector<String>> matrix = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
// Vector<String> array = new Vector<>();

while (s.hasNext()) {
  Vector<String> array = new Vector<>(); // <-- declare it here.
  String data = s.next();

  Matcher matcherDouble = patternDouble
      .matcher(data);
  Matcher matcherID = patternID.matcher(data);

  if (matcherID.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: "
        + matcherID.group(1));
    array.add(matcherID.group(1)); // <----- add the match(s)
    if (matcherDouble.find()) {    // <----- including the double.
      System.out.println("found: "
          + matcherDouble.group(3));
      array.add(matcherDouble.group(3));
    }
    /*********************************/
    if (!(array.isEmpty())) {
      matrix.add(array);
    }
    /**********************************/
    // array.clear(); <---------------------- Not needed. new vector on next iteration.
  }
}
```

Comment: +1: This looks about right.  I didn't plow through enough of the matcher code to be confident of a full replacement.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to use Map, may be you can form custom object for the of your map.

Comment: Yeah i know, i kinda have to use the Vector. Thanks though

Comment: Why do you "kinda have to use the Vector"?

Comment: I have some exam specifications, i know it can be done more easily.